# I need to write a code for a function and get an expected value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics

I need to write a code for something called a comoving sound horizon in cosmology with the equation

[image: equation]

This is the same equation with Hubble(a):
[image: equation with hubble]

Whereas the *H* function I have defined correctly for what I need, I am having trouble with coding the `r_s(z)` function(which is the comoving sound horizon). I need to get about 140 when I calculate it (with *z*=1089) but I'm getting about 250. I have included the values of constant in the code as well. (This is only for testing my code as I need to use this code to estimate parameters using emcee.)

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
H0 = 70
c = 3e5
omega_b =0.04
omega_dm = 0.26
h = (H0/100)
def Hubble(a):
    return H0*np.sqrt(((omega_b+omega_dm)/(a**3))+(1-(omega_b+omega_dm)))

def aintegrand(a):
    omega_gamma = 2.469e-5/(h**2)
    k1 = (a**2)*Hubble(a)
    k2= (3*omega_b)/(4*omega_gamma)
    return 1/(k1*np.sqrt(1+(k2*a)))

def comov1(z):
    return c*quad(aintegrand,0,(1/(1+z)))[0]/(np.sqrt(3))

print(comov1(1089))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I don't see any H function in your picture.

Comment: Not checking the function correctness, but be careful if you are working with floats to make sure you are using all numbers in the calculations as floats.  you can get some odd results with integer math that you might not expect that might influence the final result.

Comment: I take it that the `Hubble` function is the `E(a)` function. How confident are you that that function is correct?

Comment: Oh Im sorry I didnt make that clear, I totally forgot about that. The product H_0*E(a) is my Hubble(a), so E(a) is np.sqrt(the rest of the stuff)

Comment: I have also added the equation with the Hubble(a) as H(a) in the post as an edit. And I'm confident that the function I defined is correct.

Comment: Can you include the `H(a)` function in LaTeX to verify it? Also, how do you know the expected value? Did you integrate it by hand? You might be confident in `H(a)` but the rest could be wrong.

Comment: Hey thanks for trying to help, turns out I needed to include a term (which is basically zero and is usually ignored). Sorry for the trouble. I'm new to stackoverflow, how do I close this question?

Comment: `c` is wrong. It's off by a factor of 1000.

Comment: @Reinderien no it is supposed to be like that because here I am using km/s as the unit(because other measurements are in kilometers). Thanks anyways

Comment: @SreeragRadhakrishnan If you figured out the answer, you can click 'post an answer' and answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I had to add a term into the Hubble function, which is so small it is usually ignored. But adding that term fixed it. Thank you.